# Format Pdftotext output object

Tags: python, pdf-generation, word-wrap, text-formatting

I am extracting text from a Pdf file and I wanted to get a formatted output of the content. As the Object is made of a list sentences I thought that using textwrap.wrap would have had the job to work on the joined content.
I have tried with

```
for file in listoffiles
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
    
    with open("filename" + ".txt") , 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(textwrap.wrap("\n\n".join(pdf), width = 70,  ))
        f.close()
```

I have also tried with  `{:<}".format("\n\n".join(pdf)` instead of textwrap but it gives me back the dame type of result.

Is there any way to pass a clean file to the wrapper?